# Numpy's dtype conversion algorithm

Tags: python, numpy, type-conversion

How does numpy scale values, when you convert an array from a float dtype to an integer dtype, if you have an array with a max value higher than what the integer type can hold?

```
In [9]: data_array.dtype
Out[9]: dtype('<f4')

In [11]: data_array.max()
Out[11]: 32767.0

In [16]: test = np.asarray(data_array, dtype=np.int8)

In [17]: test.max()
Out[17]: 127

In [18]: data_array.max()/test.max()
Out[18]: 258.00787
```

How did numpy arrive at a scale factor of 258?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're not the same element of the array.

Numpy converts from floating to integer types by converting to int and then truncating the binary representation, so 32767.0 will convert to the integer 32767 (0x7fff) and then to 0xff, which is -1 in int8.

The 127 is coming from another array element whose integer value is congruent to 127 modulo 256.

Comment: yeah when I tested it i found that i got -1 for 32767 also but i just left that out of my answer ... (+1 for the clarification)

Comment: What do you mean by "converting to int and then truncating??" Is that a typo, should it be modulo?

Comment: @BiRico the binary representation is truncated on the left, which is equivalent to a modulo operation.

Answer (score 2):

its not a scale ... its just using 8 bits for a signed integer ...

32767 & 0b11111111 = 0b11111111 = 255 (unsigned)

int 8 is signed so it only gets 7 bits with the 8th being the sign bit

0b01111111 = 127